# MYSQL - Parameter being lost when using it in SQL statement

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure in MYSQL where I am passing one parameter which is passed into an SQL statement as you can see below however the result is returning a count of 0 where I am expecting a count of 2.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `EmployeesRecords`(IN employee_id varchar (1000))
BEGIN
    --
    declare v_count int ;
    --
    select count(*)
    into   v_count
    from  employees
    where employees_id IN (employee_id);
    --
END
```

One or many employee Id's can be passed into the parameter employee_id.

when Calling Stored Procedure like this : CALL EmployeesRecords('2,3'); This returns a count of 0 where I am expecting a count of 2

As for the parameter itself, I have tried various methods including changing it in the procedure to have it as "IN ('2','3') in the SQL condition however it still does not work.

However what I have noticed is that when passing one employee Id, it works successfully such as CALL EmployeesRecords('2');

Can anyone guide me to what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: `WHERE x IN ('a','b','c')` and `WHERE x IN ('a,b,c')` are different conditions. Use `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(employee_id, employees_id)`. And ensure that there is no excess spaces between a comma and a value (i.e. `'2,3'`, not `'2, 3'`).

Comment: CALL EmployeesRecords('2,3'); - the individual values are not seen by the in statement and is seen as a string, call('2','3') - fails because procedure expects 1 parameter but you are passing 2  , call('2') works because only 1 value is passed and tested.